# Random variables with density distributions given by squared Hermite polynomials

Tags: pr.probability, mp.mathematical-physics

I was wondering whether anything is known on the following: Let
$h_k (x)= (-1)^k e^{x^2/2} \frac {d^k}{dx^k} \, e^{-x^2/2}$, $k \geq 0$, be the classical
Hermite polynomials ($h_0(x) = 1$, $h_1(x) = x$,
$h_2(x) = x^2 -1$, $h_3(x) = x^3 - 3x$, ...).
Is there anything known on the asymptotic distributional behavior (if any), as $k \to \infty$,
of the sequence
of random variables $X_k$, $k \geq 0$, such that the law of $X_k$ has a density
proportional to $h_k^2 \, e^{-x^2/2}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$, with respect to the
Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Thank you for the indications! Would this be similar for other orthogonal polynomials (Chebyshevn Jacobi, Laguerre...)?

Comment: the approach I sketched in the answer box generalises to orthogonal polynomials that are eigenfunctions of a second order differential equation; we can then apply the WKB method to find the asymptotics at large eigenvalue; if the differential equation is of the form $-\psi''(x)+V(x)\psi(x)=E\psi(x)$, then the asymptotic probability density is $\propto [E-V(x)]^{-1/2}$. (For the Hermite polynomials of your question one has $E=4k$ and $V(x)=x^2$.)

Comment: Dear Professor Beenakker, thank you very much indeed for your detailed answer, and all the comments. I am not so familiar with physics arguments, so I need some time to fully understand the picture. I do not know how to technically "accept the answer"? (About generalizations to other orthogonal polynomials, I was also wondering similarly about discrete examples (Meixner, Krawtchouk...))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to the probability density of the [quantum harmonic oscillator.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator) (The Hermite polynomials are the eigenstates of that problem.) For large $k$ the density
$$P_k(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}k!} [h_k(x)]^2 \, e^{-x^2/2},$$
normalized to unity, has the approximation
$$p_k(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}(4k-x^2)^{-1/2},\;\;|x|<2\sqrt{k}.$$
The boundaries $\pm 2\sqrt{k}$ are the classical turning points of the harmonic oscillator. In that context $E=4k$ is the energy of the particle and $V(x)=x^2$ is the harmonic potential in which it moves. The large-$k$ approximation is known as the [WKB approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation). More generally, for an arbitrary potential $V(x)$ the density varies as $[E-V(x)]^{-1/2}$.

Alternatively, one can use the asymptotic expansion of the [Hermite polynomials,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials)
$$e^{-x^2/4}h_k(x) \propto \cos \left(x \sqrt{ k}- \pi k/2 \right)\left(4k-x^2\right)^{-1/4}.$$
Squaring and averaging over the rapidly oscillating $\cos^2$ gives $p_k(x)$.

---

[image]

The plot compares $P_k$ and $p_k$ for $k=100$. The function $p_k$ is a smoothed version of $P_k$, suitable for averaging quantities that vary little on the scale of $1/\sqrt{k}$. For example, one can check by explicit computation that the average of $x^n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, agrees to leading order in $k$,
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} k^{-n}\int P_k(x)x^{2n}\,dx=\frac{2^{2n}\,\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma(n+1)}=k^{-n}\int p_k(x) x^{2n}\,dx.$$

Comment: Do you have a proof of this approximation?

Comment: added two ways to arrive at the result, from the WKB approximation of the harmonic oscillator, or from the asymptotic expansion of the Hermite polynomials.

Comment: I do not see your approximation on the WKB approximation page. As for asymptotic expansions on the Hermite polynomials Wikipedia page, I see there clearly different, apparently mutually incompatible expansions, without a statement on the conditions for, or rigorous meaning of, those expansions. In your post too, it is unclear in what sense the approximation holds and what the sign $\propto$ means.

Comment: the sense in which $p_k(x)$ approximates $P_k(x)$ for large $k$ is as an integral kernel, I have added an example that hopefully explains this.

Comment: Can you detail the "explicit computation"? Also, a limit sign in the last display is apparently missing.

Comment: it's just a definite integral (I do these with Mathematica); there is no limit sign in the last display because that expression is $k$-independent (as one can see by changing variables from $x$ to $x/\sqrt{k}$).

Comment: Can you show that the convergence takes place, not only for polynomials, but for (say) any bounded continuous functions, so that we can then talk about the convergence in distribution?